# Client ID: Unique specified identifier

Tags: c#, sql, unique

I am working on a small project that capture customer details, Using C Sharp in Visual Studio 2010 and a SQL database.

Now i need to make my customer ID to be stored as follow, The ID needs to consist of one alphabetic characters A, B, C, D or E followed by EXACTLY EIGHT Numeric digits, these number needs to be left padded with zeroes to have exactly eight digits.

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you're asking for. You've said your requirements, but nothing about where you're stuck, what's meant to allocate the customer ID etc.

Comment: The alphabetic identifiers can be random i want to know is there a way to implement it directly in my sql database, or would it be better to hard code this. and what would the right way be to implement this o avoid duplicates and keep my application stable

Comment: @Jean, it's unclear what exactly are you asking. Are you asking how to generate the IDs? Or to check that they are in correct format? Or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Random r1 = new Random();
int num = r1.Next(0, 99999999); // generate random number
string number = string.Format("{0:D8}", num);

Random r2 = new Random();
int num2 = r2.Next(0, 26); // generate random letter
char letter = (char)('A' + num2);

string id = letter + number; // join both as ID
```

generated number may not unique, when inserting new record you may need to check whether generated ID already exist or not.

Answer (score 2):

You can generate your ID in the C# code or in the database, there are techniques to do so in both languages.

Personally I would generate it in the SQL with help of a user defined function, in this way you know that for every insert it is generated by the server and in my opinion you have good control of it, On the other hand doing so you have to retrieve it to the code to bind the value back to your entity (if needed).

as a last note, personally I would not use this field as primary key for the table, I would still use an int identity (auto increment) generated by the server as PK  (call it simply ID for example) and I would add a UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX on this CustomerID column you are mentioning.

have a look at padding leading zeros methods for SQL Server here: http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices2005/padleadingzeros/